# The meaning and usage of "whereas"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I often see the word **Whereas**  being used in formal letters in the University or at academic level. For example,

> Whereas by Charter of Her Late Majesty Queen Victoria, dated 20th April, 1880, the Victoria University was founded and constituted having its seat in the City of Manchester.
>
> — [Charter of the University of Leeds](https://www.leeds.ac.uk/secretariat/charter.html)

What is its precise meaning? What is its use in sentences?

Besides looking up its meaning in the dictionaries, I still feel uncertainty while using it in sentences. It is often used in the beginning of sentence in formal letters but I don't understand its meaning fully. I'd like to know its meaning so that I too can use it often in University.

Comment: If you know the dictionary definition of the word, what about it makes you uncertain of its meaning and usage?

Comment: When the word **Whereas** being used in the beginning of a sentence does not convey the meaning I get from  online dictionaries. One shows used as **Contrast* and the second one **Legal letters**

Comment: I love learning English language, whereas my friend does not. But, when the same word is used in beginning of some formal letters with comma (,) I usually don't get its meaning.

Comment: You should edit this additional information into the question (as comments are not permanent).

Comment: I would recommend that you not use it at all.

Comment: From Oxford Dictionaries: _(especially in legal preambles) taking into consideration the fact that_.  It's just formal legalese, not to be used in ordinary speech or writing.

Comment: Folks, try not to close-vote a new contributor's post. This Q actually belongs on [ell.se].

Comment: @KateBunting +1 I suggest migrating this Q to [ell.se], though.

Answer (score 2):

**This** use of *whereas* is well defined in Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary:

> 2. *law* : since it is true that — usually used at the beginning of a statement in an official document
>
>    > Whereas the citizens of the state of Virginia have a right to know that…

However, that is not the normal use of *whereas,* which that dictionary gives first:

> 1. — used to make a statement that describes how two people, groups, etc., are different
>
>    > - Some of these species have flourished, whereas others have struggled.
>    > - Whereas many people have supported the proposal, others have opposed it very strongly.
>    > - He has brown eyes whereas his children have green eyes.

I would wholeheartedly recommend **not** using the "law" meaning of *whereas.* It's highly specialised and **only** used in those circumstances. The "contrast" use of *whereas* is far more common.